# Design issue - What technology should i use for sending text to another user within my application?

Tags: ios, ios5, xamarin.ios, ios6

I'm creating monotouch application which is basically a quote (sayings) which is working fine .Now i need to give the users the ability to send favorite quotes to each other over the internet.For instance , user X can send any quote not by email but within the application to user Y .Sort of internal email system or exactly like "drift bottle" app in app store.

What technology should i use ? i was thinking a web service .

edit : Messaging doesn't have to be in real time.

all suggestions are welcome .

sorry for my bad english .

thank you

Comment: in what location are most of your consumers? are they local? international ?

Comment: They could be both local and international

Comment: Pirate, check out the answer and the commnet of alditis, if you are willing to pay certain amount, go check out the link I posted

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be in real time you can choose to use [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/), [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/),  [Expressjs](http://expressjs.com/) and [node-IOS](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-iOS).

Review:

- http://blog.semantics3.com/how-we-built-an-ios-app-an-android-app-and-a-node-js-api-in-20-hours/
- http://blog.amt.in/nodejs-on-android

Comment: looks interesting but I think the poster is using iOs related language . though I do not know if that will work, I'll just give it with the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: And: http://blog.semantics3.com/how-we-built-an-ios-app-an-android-app-and-a-node-js-api-in-20-hours/

Comment: Nice! I think it is best if you would put those links you gave in your answers so taht the poster could have an ease or other users seeing.

Comment: Is it supported by mobile apps and can be incorporated in monotouch framework ?

Comment: Not sure, but that would need to be another question. Sorry.

Comment: Hey alditis , I'm not a big fan of js . I was hoping for C# framework that does what i want .

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SignalR using MonoTouch](http://www.gregshackles.com/2012/07/using-signalr-in-monotouch-and-mono-for-android-apps/)

Comment: thanks man...this looks promising...i will read more about it.

Answer (score 0):

I did my fair search of googling and I found [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) Though there is a fee you that you are required to pay.

Comment: I browsed every section but it merely provide sms , voice and conferencing services for applications . It's not what i want .